# Sum of Cumulative Max of Exponentially Distributed Variables

Tags: summation, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent, identically and exponentially distributed random variables, $P(x) = k \exp(-k x)$. Define $Y$ as the sum of the sequence of cumulative maxima:

$Y = X_1 + \max(X_1, X_2) + \max(X_1, X_2, X_3) + \dots + \max(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{n})$

What distribution is followed by $Y$?

I know the formula for the distribution of $\max(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{n})$ is:

$P(z) = nk(1-\exp(-kz))^{n-1}\exp(-kz)$

But I can't see how to find the distribution of $Y$, because none of the terms in the summation are independent of each other.  I suspect some trick exploiting $\max(X_1,X_2,X_3) = \max(\max(X_1,X_2),X_3)$ will be useful here, but I'm stuck...

Comment: I doubt there is a simple solution.  You can remove the $k$ as a (reciprocal of a) scale factor, and you may be able to find an expression for the mean using linearity of expectation if you could find the expectation of the maximum of $n$, but even that might not be easy.